# updating a text widget with text from entry widgets - python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter with python to produce a quote gui.  I have 3 entry widgets (code, price and quantity) and a "Add Line" button.  When the button is pressed, I want it to take the text from each of the entry widgets and update it in the scrollable "text" widget that is located in the same window (so the user can review each line in the overall quote before submitting the final product). Any ideas?
For info, once the text widget is full of all the lines that the user wants to include in the quote, pressing another button (eg Submit) will write all of the lines into a preformatted Word document.  I have his part sorted, but cannot find how to do the first part above.  Any ideas.

Comment: use `get` to get the text from each `Entry` after that use `insert` to write to `text` widget

Answer (score 0):

To get the values from an Entry widget, use the `get` method. To insert values into a text widget use the `insert` method. These are both documented, and there are examples all over the internet.

```
def add_line():
    code = codeEntry.get()
    price = priceEntry.get()
    quantity = quantityEntry.get()
    quote.insert("end","code: %s price: %s quantity: %s\n" % (code,price,quantity))
```